# How to install wps-office on ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: 16.10, wps-office

```
nazar@android:~$ sudo dpkg -i wps*amd64.deb
[sudo] password for nazar: 
Selecting previously unselected package wps-office.
(Reading database ... 227014 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack wps-office_10.1.0.5672-a21_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking wps-office (10.1.0.5672~a21) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wps-office:
 wps-office depends on libpng12-0; however:
  Package libpng12-0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package wps-office (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.7-1) ...
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wps-office


nazar@android:~$ sudo apt-get install libpng12-0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libpng12-0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source                                                                                                                                   

E: Package 'libpng12-0' has no installation candidate



nazar@android:~$ sudo apt install -f                                                                                                                                    
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                           
Building dependency tree                                                                                                                                                
Reading state information... Done                                                                                                                                       
Correcting dependencies... Done                                                                                                                                         
The following packages will be REMOVED:                                                                                                                                 
  wps-office                                                                                                                                                            
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.                                                                                                          
1 not fully installed or removed.                                                                                                                                       
After this operation, 367 MB disk space will be freed.                                                                                                                  
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n                                                                                                                                        
Abort.        


nazar@android:~$
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Download libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u2_amd64.deb](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb). If you use a 32 bit system, download the 32 bit deb file.

Install the package and then install `wps-office`.

Comment: Download for other architectures from here- https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libpng12-0

Comment: thankx i used http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/i386/libpng12-0/download