# Unable to install WPS Office on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04

Tags: gnome, software-installation, ubuntu-gnome, wps-office

I'm trying to install WPS office in Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 , the installation through the Software App is not working (By unknown reasons at least by me) I've been able to install other software but not WPS office, so I tried with the command to install .DEB packages and it outputs the next error:

```
sudo dpkg -i wps-office_10.1.0.5672-a21_amd64.deb


(Reading database ... 216574 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack wps-office_10.1.0.5672-a21_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking wps-office (10.1.0.5672~a21) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from 'wps-office_10.1.0.5672-a21_amd64.deb' to decompressor pipe: unexpected end of file or stream
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: unexpected end of input
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive wps-office_10.1.0.5672-a21_amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot copy extracted data for './opt/kingsoft/wps-office/office6/libwppcore.so' to '/opt/kingsoft/wps-office/office6/libwppcore.so.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.8-1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wps-office_10.1.0.5672-a21_amd64.deb
```

Thank's before hand , if someone has already solved this problem I would be glad to know how , this can help other people as well, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately WPS for Linux seems to have been abandoned -> No updates since last year. For comparison, the Windows version is currently at 10.2.0.5820 – January 23 2017. Really sad and I'm afraid it's game over. The last version for Linux works in 16.04/16.10 but requires an additional library.

Comment: Oh , I didn't know it , that's really sad , I guess I will have to get used to Libre Office

Comment: I'll try to contact Kingsoft. Currently there's official announcement. The forum seems to be abandoned as well an has been a freaking SPAM orgy for years.

Comment: Okay man , I'll try as well , it was a cool office suite

Comment: Wait, don't give up yet. I was just informed that in your case it may have to do with a corrupt download. Can you please download again and try?

Comment: Okay I'll try right now again to download , I'll comment as soon as I try to install it again

Comment: Aaand , still not working , well I guess it's time to give up :(

Comment: Is it the same error message or now it complains about a missing dependency? The former means game over indeed but the latter has a workaround.

Comment: Same error man , I already installed a dependency named libpng , but that's not the error that appears

Comment: Have you checked SHA1?

Comment: It doesn't outputs any error , just a long   combination of characters

Comment: The 64bit deb must match 80d884c47eaeee3305958ed87e61eafbee30b0cf . If it doesn't then something wrong happened with the download.

Comment: b4e520bbcc4c7603d49f45d8f4fdb0c99634d5aa  wps-office_10.1.0.5672-a21_amd64.deb

Comment: That's a problem. Your download is corrupt (again).

Comment: Try this one (checksum confirmed on my side, check yours): https://mega.nz/#!gVdAHYJI!wrzQmQGwl1kEIFcYnCfptmgStCcVVFnas09vZhOwyEk

Comment: man , seriously thank you , it freaking worked , you can post an answer with your link and I'll mark it as right so this can help other people

Comment: Done, sorry for the delay. And thank you for making me investigate the issue. I suspected there was something wrong with itat the time I posted the other answer (workaround) but, since I had it installed and working, didn't care much about checking for updates.

Comment: See this solution for 16.10 which also works on 17.04.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/840412/how-to-install-wps-office-on-ubuntu-16-10/840429

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WARNING: This answer may became obsolete anytime soon. WPS for Linux seems be have been abandoned. The version you have is the last one and it may not be installable in newer Ubuntu releases.**

The original error message - `unexpected end of file or stream` - suggests corrupt download. This has been confirmed with the checksum.

Download from my [personal share](https://mega.nz/#!gVdAHYJI!wrzQmQGwl1kEIFcYnCfptmgStCcVVFnas09vZhOwyEk) and confirm SHA1 matches `80d884c47eaeee3305958ed87e61eafbee30b0cf`.

Before installing, due to a missing dependency since 16.10, this [workaround](https://askubuntu.com/a/872345/589808) is still required.
You should now be able to install and enjoy this great office suite that unfortunately reached the end of its life.

Comment: alternative link: https://app.box.com/s/f5pp05570oq9j4jac6r35xzgy35g42ww

Comment: Just for the record, I've just downloaded the file and the SHA matches. Might have been a temporary server issue or something similar.

Comment: @KazWolfe That's probably it. When I downloaded (with DownThemAll) I had to pause and restart 3 times. Kingsoft's servers were never that good. Years ago it would takes hours, literally.

Answer (score 2):

Using `gdebi` (instead of `dpkg`) as manual package installer, it gives you the error that the `libpng12-0` package is missing.

This package shall be downloaded following those links  :

http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/i386/libpng12-0/download

http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpng12-0/download

(according to [this  *Ask Ubuntu* thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840257/e-package-libpng12-0-has-no-installation-candidate-ubuntu-16-10-gnome/840268))

Then install this package with `dpkg` (`gdebi` raises an error ...). In my case :

`sudo dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb`

And finally install WPS :

`sudo dpkg -i wps-office_10.1.0.5672~a21_amd64.deb`

And normally WPS is installed and works.